# C# XBAP QueryString (BrowserInteropHelper.Source.Query) Above 2080 Characters Problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I'm passing a very long argument string to a C# XBAP application, and I'm using the BrowserInteropHelper.Source.Query method to read the argument string.  But, for some reason, everytime the string for the arguments goes about 2080 characters, the application fails.

Have I exceeded the maximum length?  Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where are you sending the data? Other window? From within the same web page?

You have probably exceeded the length for querystring so I am trying to figure out another way.

What about passing data through javascript within the page or using POST instead of GET when sending from another web page?

Edit:
I would try to move the SL from iframe directly to the page. -you would be able to communicate with the SL application directly through JS then. Especially, if you need to send the data only once when the SL application starts, you should pass it as parameters to the  hosting the SL.

If getting rid of the iframe is not possible, pass the parameters through POST (a form sent).

Comment: I'm sending the arguments to an iFrame, that hosts the actual XBAP